# How do I find a "Bitcoin address" for buying Bitcoin?

Tags: wallet

I am very new to Bitcoin and just learning my way around my Bitcoin wallet, etc. Recently, in order to try to find out more about buying Bitcoin, I clicked on "Buy Bitcoin" in my wallet, but was immediately required to "enter Bitcoin address" before I could go any further.  I don't know what to enter here, or how to find out.  Can someone enlighten me, please ?

Comment: What do you mean by "in my wallet"? Was there some specific web page or program that you were using?

Answer (score 3):

You have to download a Bitcoin wallet first. I suggest you to download [Electrum](https://electrum.org/#home), it's a lightweight wallet with easy UI. It will generate an address for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your bitcoin address via here: http://www.bitaddress.org -- make sure you write down or print out your generated private key. You enter your public key into your app you mentioned.

Comment: This is terrible advice.

Comment: @MaxVernon No, BitAddress is completely client side and famous. The reason that it was not a good advice was that, that website only generates an address, and doesn't have a wallet that you can use to make a transaction, see your balance, etc.. The main point here is "If someone asks 'How to generate an address', we should also mention that generating an address is not enough make transactions, a wallet is also needed"

Comment: @MCCCS - perhaps you could improve the answer by adding that the OP would need to have a wallet setup with the keys generated by bitaddress prior to sending transactions to it to avoid losing their money.  I'd guess it might also be important to add guidance making sure they use bitaddress completely offline.